# Double count result when using INNER JOIN on TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the following query to count all scripts runs, but when there are 2 types for a software, it doubles the count result.

Here is query I'm using:

```
SELECT 
    p.produto, p.pacote, 
    COUNT(p.produto) AS Execuções, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim)) / 60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim)) % 60), 2) AS [Tempo Médio (Automatizado)], 
    t.tempo_minutos AS [Tempo Médio (Manual)], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, (t.tempo_minutos * 60 - AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim))) / 60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, (t.tempo_minutos * 60 - AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim))) % 60), 2) AS [Economia Média], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, (t.tempo_minutos * 60 - AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim))) * COUNT(p.produto) / 60)  + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, (t.tempo_minutos * 60 - AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim))) * COUNT(p.produto) % 60), 2) AS [Economia Total]
FROM 
    [log].pdq AS p 
INNER JOIN 
    infra.tempo_medio_execucao AS t ON t.produto = p.produto
WHERE 
    (p.equipamento NOT LIKE 'XXX%') AND (p.status = 'Sucesso')
GROUP BY 
    p.produto, p.pacote, t.tempo_minutos
```

This query is returning the following result (removed the unnecessary info from the table):

```
produto  | pacote        | Execuções
---------+---------------+-----------    
SafeSign | Desinstalação | 6
SafeSign | Instalação    | 18
ScanBack | Instalação    | 128
```

Where it should return:

```
produto  | pacote        |  Execuções
---------+---------------+-----------    
SafeSign | Desinstalação | 3
SafeSign | Instalação    | 9
ScanBack | Instalação    | 128
```

In the infra.tempo_medio_execucao table, I have this data:

```
produto      | pacote        | tempo_minutos 
-------------+---------------+--------------
ScanBack     | Instalação    | 20
Siric Zero   | Instalação    | 20
GRRF         | Instalação    | 90
SICCH        | Instalação    | 15
Outlook 2013 | Instalação    | 25
7-Zip        | Instalação    | 20
7-Zip        | Desinstalação | 20
SafeSign     | Instalação    | 20
SafeSign     | Desinstalação | 20
```

The table log.pdq will return:

```
id | produto   | pacote      | inicio                  | fim                     | duracao          | status 
---+-----------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+--------
1  | ScanBack  | Instalação  | 2018-09-18 11:22:54.000 | 2018-09-18 11:27:43.000 | 00:04:49.0000000 | Sucesso 
2  | ScanBack  | Instalação  | 2018-09-18 12:10:46.000 | 2018-09-18 12:11:04.000 | 00:00:17.0000000 | Sucesso 
3  | ScanBack  | Instalação  | 2018-09-18 12:10:49.000 | 2018-09-18 12:11:17.000 | 00:00:27.0000000 | Sucesso 
4  | GRRF      | Instalação  | 2018-09-18 12:28:43.000 | 2018-09-18 12:29:14.000 | 00:00:30.0000000 | Sucesso
```

And the view I've created returns: (but for Safesign, it should return 3 and 9, not 6 and 18)

```
Produto    |  Pacote       | Execuções  | Tempo Médio (Automatizado) | Tempo Médio (Manual) | Economia Média  | Economia Total
-----------+---------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+----------------
GRRF       | Instalação    | 1          | 0:31                       | 90                   | 89:29           | 89:29
SafeSign   | Desinstalação | 6          | 0:00                       | 20                   | 20:00           | 120:00
SafeSign   | Instalação    | 18         | 1:19                       | 20                   | 18:41           | 336:18
ScanBack   | Instalação    | 128        | 1:23                       | 20                   | 18:37           | 2382:56
SICCH      | Instalação    | 7          | 0:34                       | 15                   | 14:26           | 101:02
Siric Zero | Instalação    | 208        | 0:33                       | 20                   | 19:27           | 4045:36
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you want `count distinct`?

Comment: As Andrew stated, does "COUNT(DISTINCT p.produto)" work? Although, if you aren't getting back a single row, the better solution is to fix it so there is a one to one join. Can you provide table definitions and sample data?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried count distinct. It returns all values as 1.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you remove your `GROUP BY` and replace your columns with a star (ie: `SELECT *`) it might give you an idea why you have duplicates. It's hard to tell without knowing what data you have

Comment: Try adding t.tempo_minutos as one of the displayed columns, since you are grouping by it.

Comment: I have updated the post with all the information properly formated.

Comment: Hi Jon Wilson, I alread have it added and named as Tempo Médio (Manual).

Answer (score 0):

There is really something missing in your question. This seems to produce the correct result; so, I think you need to provide a better example.

```
DECLARE @pdq TABLE (
    ID int,produto nvarchar(50),pacote nvarchar(50),inicio datetime2,fim datetime2,duracao time, status nvarchar(50),equipamento nvarchar(50)
)

DECLARE @tempo_medio_execucao  TABLE (
    produto nvarchar(50),pacote nvarchar(50),tempo_minutos INT
)

INSERT INTO @pdq(id,produto,pacote,inicio,fim,duracao,status,equipamento) SELECT 1,'ScanBack','Instalação','2018-09-18 11:22:54.000','2018-09-18 11:27:43.000','00:04:49.0000000','Sucesso','Unknown'
INSERT INTO @pdq(id,produto,pacote,inicio,fim,duracao,status,equipamento) SELECT 2,'ScanBack','Instalação','2018-09-18 12:10:46.000','2018-09-18 12:11:04.000','00:00:17.0000000','Sucesso','Unknown'
INSERT INTO @pdq(id,produto,pacote,inicio,fim,duracao,status,equipamento) SELECT 3,'ScanBack','Instalação','2018-09-18 12:10:49.000','2018-09-18 12:11:17.000','00:00:27.0000000','Sucesso','Unknown'
INSERT INTO @pdq(id,produto,pacote,inicio,fim,duracao,status,equipamento) SELECT 4,'GRRF','Instalação','2018-09-18 12:28:43.000','2018-09-18 12:29:14.000','00:00:30.0000000','Sucesso','Unknown'

INSERT INTO @tempo_medio_execucao(produto,pacote,tempo_minutos) SELECT 'ScanBack','Instalação',20
INSERT INTO @tempo_medio_execucao(produto,pacote,tempo_minutos) SELECT 'Siric Zero','Instalação',20
INSERT INTO @tempo_medio_execucao(produto,pacote,tempo_minutos) SELECT 'GRRF','Instalação',90
INSERT INTO @tempo_medio_execucao(produto,pacote,tempo_minutos) SELECT 'SICCH','Instalação',15
INSERT INTO @tempo_medio_execucao(produto,pacote,tempo_minutos) SELECT 'Outlook 2013','Instalação',25
INSERT INTO @tempo_medio_execucao(produto,pacote,tempo_minutos) SELECT '7-Zip','Instalação',20
INSERT INTO @tempo_medio_execucao(produto,pacote,tempo_minutos) SELECT '7-Zip','Desinstalação',20
INSERT INTO @tempo_medio_execucao(produto,pacote,tempo_minutos) SELECT 'SafeSign','Instalação',20
INSERT INTO @tempo_medio_execucao(produto,pacote,tempo_minutos) SELECT 'SafeSign','Desinstalação',20

SELECT 
    p.produto, p.pacote, 
    COUNT(p.produto) AS Execuções, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim)) / 60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim)) % 60), 2) AS [Tempo Médio (Automatizado)], 
    t.tempo_minutos AS [Tempo Médio (Manual)], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, (t.tempo_minutos * 60 - AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim))) / 60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, (t.tempo_minutos * 60 - AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim))) % 60), 2) AS [Economia Média], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, (t.tempo_minutos * 60 - AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim))) * COUNT(p.produto) / 60)  + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, (t.tempo_minutos * 60 - AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.inicio, p.fim))) * COUNT(p.produto) % 60), 2) AS [Economia Total]
FROM @pdq AS p 
INNER JOIN @tempo_medio_execucao AS t ON t.produto = p.produto
WHERE (p.equipamento NOT LIKE 'XXX%') AND (p.status = 'Sucesso')
GROUP BY 
    p.produto, p.pacote, t.tempo_minutos
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this does what you specify in the question:

```
SELECT p.produto, p.pacote, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.produto) AS Execuções, 
       . . .
```

You would be getting duplicates from your joins -- basically unexpected matches.

However, it is quite possible (likely) that other columns are also inaccurate.  If this fixes the issue with `Execuções`, but you still have other issues, then ask *another* question.  Be very clear about sample data, desired results, and what needs to be fixed.