# Double count result on TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the following query to count all scripts runs, but when there are 2 types for a software (pacote column), it doubles the count result.

```sql
SELECT  
     p.produto, p.pacote, COUNT(p.produto) AS Execuções, t.tempo_minutos AS [Tempo Médio (Manual)]
FROM 
     [log].pdq AS p 
INNER JOIN 
     infra.tempo_medio_execucao AS t ON t.produto = p.produto
WHERE 
     (p.status IS NOT NULL) AND (p.status = 'Sucesso') AND (p.produto = 'SafeSign')
GROUP BY 
      p.produto, p.pacote, t.tempo_minutos
```

This query is returning the following result:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ produto  ║    pacote     ║ Execuções ║ Tempo Médio (Manual) ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ SafeSign ║ Desinstalação ║         6 ║                   20 ║
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║        18 ║                   20 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

But if I remove the INNER JOIN part of the code, it returns the desired count value. But my query requires an INNER JOIN with infra.tempo_medio_execucao table.

```sql
SELECT  
     p.produto, p.pacote, COUNT(p.produto) AS Execuções
FROM 
     [log].pdq AS p 
WHERE 
     (p.status IS NOT NULL) AND (p.status = 'Sucesso') AND (p.produto = 'SafeSign')
GROUP BY 
      p.produto, p.pacote
```

This new query will produce the following result (which is the expected result when executing the INNER JOIN query):

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ produto  ║    pacote     ║ Execuções ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ SafeSign ║ Desinstalação ║         3 ║
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║         9 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Here are some additional information from the tables related to this query:

Data from infra.tempo_medio_execucao:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ produto  ║    pacote     ║ tempo_minutos ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║            20 ║
║ SafeSign ║ Desinstalação ║            20 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Data from log.pdq:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦═════════╗
║ produto  ║    pacote     ║         inicio          ║           fim           ║     duracao      ║ status  ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═════════╣
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║ 2018-11-09 13:06:00.000 ║ 2018-11-09 13:07:29.000 ║ 00:01:28.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
║ SafeSign ║ Desinstalação ║ 2018-11-09 13:21:19.000 ║ 2018-11-09 13:21:20.000 ║ 00:00:00.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║ 2018-11-09 13:27:52.000 ║ 2018-11-09 13:28:55.000 ║ 00:01:03.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║ 2018-11-09 13:34:08.000 ║ 2018-11-09 13:34:58.000 ║ 00:00:50.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
║ SafeSign ║ Desinstalação ║ 2018-11-09 13:38:19.000 ║ 2018-11-09 13:38:19.000 ║ 00:00:00.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
║ SafeSign ║ Desinstalação ║ 2018-11-09 14:04:34.000 ║ 2018-11-09 14:04:35.000 ║ 00:00:00.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║ 2018-11-09 14:09:41.000 ║ 2018-11-09 14:10:15.000 ║ 00:00:33.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║ 2018-11-09 14:09:57.000 ║ 2018-11-09 14:11:49.000 ║ 00:01:52.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║ 2018-11-09 13:17:01.000 ║ 2018-11-09 13:19:37.000 ║ 00:02:36.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║ 2018-11-09 13:17:01.000 ║ 2018-11-09 13:17:44.000 ║ 00:00:42.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║ 2018-11-09 14:28:16.000 ║ 2018-11-09 14:30:32.000 ║ 00:02:15.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
║ SafeSign ║ Instalação    ║ 2018-11-09 15:30:34.000 ║ 2018-11-09 15:31:06.000 ║ 00:00:32.0000000 ║ Sucesso ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩═════════╝
```

As per log.pdq table, there are 12 entries. 3 from Desinstalação and 9 from Instalação.

For some reason, when using count produto and not using the INNER JOIN function, it will return the correct count. But when using it, it will double the results.

I have already asked this question, but with poor formatting and info quality. Thus, it could not be answered. Then this question as created with better explanation, data, formatting, making it get answered in a few minutes.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Don't you also need to include `pacote` field in the join condition? It is present in both tables.

Comment: Yay! It worked Salman A! Thanks a lot for the help! This problem was giving me nightmares.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double count result when using INNER JOIN on TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231534/double-count-result-when-using-inner-join-on-tsql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to include the `pacote` field in the `JOIN` condition:

```
infra.tempo_medio_execucao AS t ON t.produto = p.produto AND t.pacote = p.pacote
```

Without this condition each row is multiplied by *both* rows in the tempo_medio_execucao table creating the duplicate.